# generating dynamic info windows php Javascript Googlemaps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I wanna be able to dynamically generate the info for each info window using the php for loop i created due to certain variables in locations[i][3] so it will dynamically pull the information on each pass and i can simply assign it. but for some reason if i try to insert this. the code generates fine ... on the source page... but the map wont even load.. does anyone have a fix for this... and to help make it work... MUCH THX in ADVANCE!! the info has been dynamically pulled in a seperate script the $vars are just used for the count to pull the information from the individual arrays. the map markers generate fine with the lats and lng's its that [i][3] part of the location array thats being funky and -- ps. yes the $vars in the code have been set to zero again. but thats in the side script. so it DOES pull all the proper info. for the [3] string - the map just does not generate in the array.

```
'<'script type="text/javascript">

    //PHP - Lat,Lng ARRAY
    var locations = [

    php code <?php
    $x = 0; $i = 0; $j = 0;
    for($aa = 0; $aa < $count; $aa++) {
    echo "['" . $business_name[$x] . "'," . $lat[$i] . "," . $lng[$j] . "," . "<div class='coupon'><div class='ribbon'><div class='ribbon-stitches-top'></div><strong class='ribbon-content'><h1>$deal[$y]</h1></strong><div class='ribbon-stitches-bottom'></div></div><div class='picture_coupon'><img src='$deal_photo[$b]' width='150' height='100' /></div><div class='deal'><center><h1>$deal[$y]</h1>$deal_info[$a]<b>Expires: $deal_expiration[$c]</b></center></div></div>" . "],";
    $x++; $i++; $j++; $id++;
    }
    ?>  END of PHP CODE
    [ , , , ]
    //['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 6]
    ];  
    //PHP - Lat,Lng ARRAY 
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);

        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                             position.coords.longitude);

// INVERSE CODE PHP DYNAMIC

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    var image = '../images/map-icons/blue.png';
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: image
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][3]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
/* */
// INVERSE CODE PHP DYNAMIC 
// GEO LOCATION SET CENTER AND ERROR HANDLING
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
      }

      function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
          var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
          var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }   
// GEO LOCATION SET CENTER AND ERROR HANDLING       

      }

    //  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED -- unfortunately the echo ""; function doesnt allow anything but ('') on the inside of it to separate divs etc. unfortunately the javascript will not load with anything but STANDARD html inside of it. not PHP's variation.

solution was to set the string with proper html standards ie  instead of  and used the concatenation operator.

ex:

```
$content = '<div class="coupon"><div class="ribbon"><div class="ribbon-stitches-top"></div><strong class="ribbon-content"><h1>'.$deal[$y].'</h1></strong><div class="ribbon-stitches-bottom"></div></div><div class="picture_coupon"><img src="'.$deal_photo[$b].'" width="150" height="100" /></div><div class="deal"><center><h1>'.$deal[$y].'</h1>'.$deal_info[$a].'<b>Expires: '.$deal_expiration[$c].'</b></center></div></div>';
```

and i assigned that to the array loop to look like this

```
    <?php
$x = 0; $i = 0; $j = 0; $y = 0; $z = 0; $a = 0; $b = 0; $c = 0;
for($aa = 0; $aa < $count; $aa++) {
$content = '<div class="coupon"><div class="ribbon"><div class="ribbon-stitches-top"></div><strong class="ribbon-content"><h1>'.$deal[$y].'</h1></strong><div class="ribbon-stitches-bottom"></div></div><div class="picture_coupon"><img src="'.$deal_photo[$b].'" width="150" height="100" /></div><div class="deal"><center><h1>'.$deal[$y].'</h1>'.$deal_info[$a].'<b>Expires: '.$deal_expiration[$c].'</b></center></div></div>';

echo "['" . $business_name[$x] . "'," . $lat[$i] . "," . $lng[$j] . "," . "'$content'" . "],";
$x++; $i++; $j++; $id++; $y++; $z++; $a++; $b++; $c++;
}
?>
```

i know nothing of javascript when it comes to what it allows for the goog.... so coming to that conclusion hurt my brain more than i could even imagine...